# running over list valuse C++ eclipse

Tags: c++, list, operators, copy-constructor

I have a class named Movie, which holds a list of pointers to Genres. problem is, everytime I wish to do operator+ on 2 movies with 2 different Genres, I want the union of them to have both different Movies A and B. instead, one of them runs over the other..

```
class MovieIndustry {


list<Movie> movies; //list of pointers to relevant type of Workers
list<Genre> genres;
Movie final;
Genre* toAdd;

void MovieIndustry::addMoviesTogether(string allMovies) {

 std::list<Movie> moviesToAdd; //HAS MOVIES, CODE WORKS, NOT THE PROBLEM..
 int i=0;
 Movie temp;

 bool cutSpace=true;
 bool notFound=false;
 for (std::string each; std::getline(split, each, split_char);  
   tokens.push_back(each))
 {
   if(cutSpace)
   {
       each= each.substr(1);
       cutSpace=false;
   }

   int k;

   for (std::list<Movie>::iterator it2=movies.begin(); it2!= movies.end();      
       ++it2) 
                {
                   k++;
                    if( it2->getCode() == each)
                    {

                        moviesToAdd.push_back(*it2);
                    }

                    if(k==movies.size())
                    {
                        notFound=true;
                        break;   
                    }
                }//end for
  }//endfor

  if(notFound) //MEANS THERE IS NOT MOVIE WITH SUCH A CODE
   return;

   for (std::list<Movie>::iterator it2=moviesToAdd.begin(); 
   it2!=moviesToAdd.end(); ++it2) 
    {
       i++;
         if(i==1) //I don't want to overload NULL
            {
              final=*it2;
              continue;
            }
          else
           {
             temp=final;
             final =  temp + *it2;
           }
 }// end for
movies.push_back(final)
}

Movie Movie:: operator+ (const Movie& other) const{

Movie toReturn,toCheck;
Worker* toAdd,toChecking;
Genre* genreAdd,GenreChecking;
std::list<Genre*>::const_iterator checkOther;
std::list<Genre*>::const_iterator genresOfLonger;


if(length >other.getLength())
{
    toReturn=*this;
    toCheck=other;
}
else
{
    //cout<< "inside right else"<<endl;
    toReturn = other;
    toCheck = *this;

}

if(toCheck.getNumOfGenres() > 0 )
    {
        int i=0;
        int firstNum = toReturn.getNumOfGenres();
    for (checkOther=toCheck.getGenresInMovie().begin(); 
    i != toCheck.getNumOfGenres(); ++checkOther)
    {
        i++;
        int j=0;

        if(firstNum==0) //ADDED THEM ALL, BECAUSE THE FIRST HAS NO GENRES
        {
            genreAdd= (*checkOther);
            toReturn.addGenre(genreAdd);
            genreAdd = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
        for (genresOfLonger=toReturn.getGenresInMovie().begin(); j!= 
        firstNum; ++genresOfLonger)//look for it
        {
                j++;
                if( (*genresOfLonger)-> getName() == (*checkOther) -
                  >getName())
                {
                    break; //leave loop, look for next one
                }
                else
                {
                    if  ( j== firstNum) //its not here, add it
                    {
                    genreAdd= (*checkOther);
                    toReturn.addGenre(genreAdd);
                    genreAdd = NULL;
                    }
                } //end  else
        }//end for
        }//end else
    }

    }//endif

return toReturn;
```

this is operator= :

```
Movie& Movie:: operator= (const Movie& other) {
Genre* genrePointer;
if (other.getNumOfGenres () > 0  )
{

    int k=0;
    for (std::list<Genre*>::const_iterator 
    git=other.getGenresInMovie().begin();k!= other.getNumOfGenres(); ++git)
            {
                    k++;
                    genrePointer= (*git);
                    this->addGenre(genrePointer);
                    genrePointer=NULL;
                }
 }
return *this;
```

and my copy constructor's simply:

```
Movie::Movie(const Movie& toCopy) {
 *this=toCopy;
 }
```

while detecting it, I found that when i send my parameter b to operator +, IT ALREADY HAS THE GENRE OF A and B as well.. i dont get it

as I mentioned,problem is, say MOVIE A has scifi, MOVIE B has Action, and if I want to add them into MOVIE final=A+B, final gets genres "Action,Action".
Im quite sure the problem is in this loop, because when i send to the operator+ and operator= from a different function it all works out as expected..
HELP..?

Comment: *because when i send to the operator+ and operator= from a different function it all works out as expected* -- Please post these operators.  If they worked, then there would be no issue.  Also, where did `temp` come from?  It just appears out of nowhere in the code you posted.

Comment: just added operator+, im working on = to add it here

Comment: This is not valid code. Please include things like closing braces, and possibly format your code before pasting ;)

Comment: ...and I deleted my answer

Comment: @aviadm71 *I ADDED EVERYTHING* -- Not enough to give a concrete answer.  There are flaws in your `operator=`.  The major flaw is that if there is an exception thrown during the call, you will have a partial list and not a full list.  Second, you should really post the code to what you're calling.  The `getGenresInMovie` call for example.  Does that return a reference or a copy?  Also, post the member variables of the `Movie` class.  Again, this is important to determine if your assignment and copy constructor are written correctly.

Comment: @aviadm71 We also don't know what the `Movie` destructor looks like.  That function is important for any of this to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the same thing as tobi, until I saw `//HAS MOVIES, CODE WORKS, NOT THE PROBLEM..`

You could use [set_union](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_union/) if you sort both genre lists beforehand.